# COUNT(*) OVER ()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have a `COUNT(*) OVER ()` as part of my query to fetch a large amount of data with about 15 joins to tables (some big, some small). What's the best solution for count here?

1. Separate query to find count.
2. COUNT(*) OVER () as part of the query that fetches the data (since it is going to calculate count for each row?!)
3. Or a query to get count union the query to fetch data. (Of course, I will have to put null for all the other columns the data query is going to fetch.)

Comment: (a) I have to question the sensibility of the design that leads to a "large" query that requires 15 joins. (b) Is there any reason you can't just rely on `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;` after the query finishes? Are you using pagination or something?

Comment: Yes, pagination is in place. But a total count is needed. Also, legacy DB, can't change schema, indexing and partitioning is in place.

Comment: [This post](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) and the comments may be useful. [Also, see this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352471/getting-total-row-count-from-offset-fetch-next).

Comment: "*since its going calculate count for each row*" - I don't think SQL will do that. As the `over()` essentially means "calculate all rows", I would expect the SQL Server optimizer to be smart enough to only do that once. But only the execution plan can prove that.

Answer (score 11):

`COUNT(*) OVER ()` is one of those operations that sounds like it ought to be cheap for the query optimizer. After all, SQL Server already knows how many rows are returned by the query. You're just asking it to project that value into the result set of the query. Unfortunately, `COUNT(*) OVER ()` can be an expensive operation depending on the query that you're adding it to.

For a simple test I'll put a moderate amount of testing into a table. Really any table will do, but here is my sample data for those following along at home:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(REPLICATE('A', 100) AS VARCHAR(100)) ID1
, CAST(REPLICATE('Z', 100) AS VARCHAR(100)) ID2
  INTO #JUNK_DATA
FROM master..spt_values t1
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2;
```

This query takes 2.5 seconds when discarding result sets:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 
FROM #JUNK_DATA;
```

This query takes 2.7 seconds when run serially but can parallelize:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #JUNK_DATA
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

The query with the `COUNT` aggregate query takes 47.2 seconds to complete on my machine.

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, COUNT(*) OVER () CNT
FROM #JUNK_DATA;
```

Perhaps my machine has issues but it's definitely doing more work. Here's the query plan:

[image: bad plan]

SQL Server is loading all of the column values into a table spool then reading that data twice and joining it together. Why is it doing all of that work when it already knows how many rows are in the result set?

SQL Server query plans process data one row at a time (more or less) in a streaming fashion. So if we calculated the number of rows as it went it might look like this:

```
╔═════╦═════╦══════════════╗
║ ID1 ║ ID2 ║ COUNT_SO_FAR ║
╠═════╬═════╬══════════════╣
║ A   ║ B   ║ 1            ║
║ C   ║ D   ║ 2            ║
║ E   ║ F   ║ 3            ║
║ ... ║ ... ║ ...          ║
║ ZZZ ║ ZZZ ║ 6431296      ║
╚═════╩═════╩══════════════╝
```

That operation doesn't require a separate copy of the data, but how can the final value of 6431296 be applied to all of the previous rows? Sometimes this operation is implemented as the double spool that we saw in the query plan. It is possible to imagine more efficient internal algorithms that we'd like SQL Server to use but we obviously don't have direct control over that.

As I see it here are the your options to solve your problem:

1. Fix the application. SQL Server already knows how many rows that the query will return. Using `@@ROWCOUNT` or some other method is by far the most preferable.
2. Run a separate query to get the count. This can be a good choice if you're returning a large result set to the client and your data is guaranteed not to change inbetween queries. The separate `COUNT` may benefit from parallelism and from having the relevant tables already loaded into the buffer cache. Depending on indexes on the tables SQL Server may be able to do less IO to get the count as opposed to the full result set.
3. Add the `COUNT` aggregate to the query. This can be a good choice if your typical result set is small. That way you don't load as much data into the spool.

The rest of this answer contains information about some tricks that can be done with window functions. Not all of them are relevant to your version of SQL Server, 2008.

A simple `ROW_NUMBER()` addition does not require the result set to be put into a table spool. If you think about the earlier example that makes sense. SQL Server can just calculate the value as it goes and it doesn't need to apply a value to a previous row. This query ran in 3.1 seconds on my machine:

```
SELECT 
  ID1
, ID2
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
FROM #JUNK_DATA;
```

We can see this in the query plan:

[image: simple RN]

If you change your application to simply take the maximum value of `RN` as the count of rows then this could be a good option for you.

You might be tempted to use `ROW_NUMBER()` along with a `UNION ALL` to get the value that you're looking for in the final dummy row, similar to what you proposed in your question. For example:

```
SELECT
  t.ID1
, t.ID2
, CASE WHEN ROW_COUNT_ROW = 'Y' THEN -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ELSE NULL END ROW_COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      ID1
    , ID2
    , 'N' ROW_COUNT_ROW
    FROM #JUNK_DATA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      NULL ID1
    , NULL ID2
    , 'Y' ROW_COUNT_ROW
) t;
```

The above query finished in 3.4 seconds and returned the correct results for me. However, but because it relies on an unspecified join order it can also return the wrong results. Looking at the plan:

[image: unsafe union all]

The part of the query in blue has to be the top part of the concatenation. The part of the query in red has to be the bottom half. The query optimization is free to rearrange the query plan or to implement the `UNION` with a different physical operator so you may not always get correct results.

As of SQL Server 2012 it's possible to use the `LEAD` window function to accomplish something similar to the above example:

```
SELECT
  t.ID1
, t.ID2
, CASE WHEN LD IS NULL THEN RN ELSE NULL END ROW_COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    , LEAD(ID1) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) LD
    FROM #JUNK_DATA
) t;
```

This query avoids the explicit table spool and it feels safer than the other one. After all, why would SQL Server process the window functions in a different order? However, correct results are not guaranteed and it finishes in 12.5 seconds on my machine.

It is possible to add an explicit `ORDER` to the query to always get the right results:

```
SELECT
  t.ID1
, t.ID2
, CASE WHEN ORDER_BY_COL = 1 THEN -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_BY_COL) ELSE NULL END ROW_COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT
      ID1
    , ID2
    , 0 ORDER_BY_COL
    FROM #JUNK_DATA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      NULL ID1
    , NULL ID2
    , 1 ORDER_BY_COL
) t
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

But this requires an expensive sort operator in the query plan:

[image: ORDER BY plan]

The query ran in 21.5 seconds in serial and would have finished faster if I let it run in parallel.

Finally, as of SQL Server 2016 it's possible to [add batch mode for the operators that implement the window functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/what-you-need-know-about-batch-mode-window-aggregate-operator-sql-server-2016-part-1). I'm going to create an empty CCI table and add it to the query:

```
CREATE TABLE #ADD_BATCH_MODE (
ID INT NOT NULL, 
INDEX CCI_BATCH CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
);

SELECT ID1, ID2, COUNT(*) OVER () ROW_COUNT
FROM #JUNK_DATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ADD_BATCH_MODE ON 1 = 0;
```

This tricks SQL Server into using batch mode for the aggregate. Here is the plan:

[image: window aggregate]

The query certainly looks simpler. The on-disk spool is no longer present and it finishes in 5.4 seconds. Adding batch mode to a complicated query will have other effects and in general they will be positive ones but you can't know without testing.

Answer (score -1):

These analytical functions have been invented to do stuff in a single pass. So depending on the size of your tables it might be the right thing to do.

You have to check what the query optimizer is doing. I have seen cases, where `count(*)` has been retrieved from the smallest index.
YMMV